# Rails 5: ArgumentError: Unknown key: :uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

> ArgumentError: Unknown key: :uniqueness. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type, :index_errors

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base 
    validates :user_id, presence: true  
    has_one :user
    has_many :teams, uniqueness: { 
    scope: [:user_id],
    message: 'You can only create one team per league'
  }
end
```

There are multiple teams in a league, but the teams must have a unique user_id.

```
create_table "leagues", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string "name"
  t.string "key"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_leagues_on_user_id"
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string "name"
  t.string "players"
  t.integer "league_id"
  t.index ["league_id"], name: "index_teams_on_league_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_teams_on_user_id"
end
```

`validates :user_id, presence: true` and  `has_one :user` is in relation to the User who created the league.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ArgumentError: Unknown key: :uniqueness. Valid keys are: :class_name,
>   :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name,
>   :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend,
>   :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type,
>   :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type, :index_errors

The error says it all! You are passing an **Invalid key**(`uniqueness`) to the `has_many` association. I believe you are trying to do a **uniqueness validation** and instead mixing it up on a `has_many` association. I suggest you to read these [*Guides*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Just a note, having only the rails uniqueness validation is not always enough.   It leaves you open to a race condition where 2 near simultaneous requests to create the same data (end user clicked submit 2x) both get added.  The standard practice is to do both rails validation and database validation for uniqueness.   [This Link](https://rietta.com/blog/2015/05/04/validates-uniqueness-race-condition-in-ruby-on-rails/) explains in further detail how this happens and how to set it up

Comment: @MichaelGorman Yep! I'm aware of it. That will come later when OP has figured out what he is doing wrong! My answer says what's wrong. That's it :)